# How to define List.flatten without using the standard library?

Tags: list, ocaml, flatten

At first the code was in `List.flatten` (OCaml standard Library). However, i don't want to use standard library. Therefore I define `flatten` function. It works fine during `List.flatten`. after i implement custom_flatten, it shows "Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int"

May I know what is wrong with my `custom_flatten` function?

Code Snippet:

```
type move = Fill of int | Drain of int | Transfer of int * int;;


type state = {
  jar_volumes: int list;
  current_state: int list;
  moves: move list;
}

let rec reversed lst =
  let rec reverse acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | head :: tail -> reverse (head :: acc) tail
  in
  reverse [] lst;;

let rec mapi_Two f index list =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | x :: xs ->
    let result = f index x in
    result :: mapi_Two f (index + 1) xs

(*Error after implement this*)
let custom_flatten lst =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | [] :: xs -> aux acc xs
    | (h :: t) :: xs -> aux (h :: acc) (t :: xs)
  in
  reversed (aux [] lst)

let generate_transfers jar_idx jar_count =
  let transfer_indices =
    init jar_count (fun target_idx -> (jar_idx, target_idx))
  in
  filter (fun (source, target) -> source <> target) transfer_indices
  |> mapi_Two (fun (source, target) i -> Transfer (source, target))

(*The only flatten is in this function*)
let generate_possible_moves state =
  let jar_count = length state.jar_volumes in
  let generate_fills_and_drains jar_idx = [Fill jar_idx; Drain jar_idx] in
  let generate_transfers jar_idx = generate_transfers jar_idx jar_count in
  let moves_for_jar jar_idx =
    (generate_fills_and_drains jar_idx) @ (generate_transfers jar_idx)
  in
  custom_flatten (mapi_Two (fun i _ -> moves_for_jar i) 0 state.jar_volumes)

let perform_move state move =
  let new_state = doMove state.jar_volumes state.current_state move in
  { state with current_state = new_state; moves = move :: state.moves }
```

The error only appeared after I changed the `flatten` function.

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int
```

---

Edit by RichardHuxton: this is your actual error and what it points to:

```
File "stackoverflow_20231025.ml", line 38, characters 19-35:
38 |   |> mapi_Two (fun (source, target) i -> Transfer (source, target))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int
```

That is after I changed `init jarcount ...` to `List.init jarcount`.

Comment: Where is the error? What did you try to solve the issue?

Comment: At first the code was in list. flatten (Ocaml standard Library). However, i don't want to use standard library. Therefore I define flatten function. It works fine during list.flatten. 

after i implement custom_flatten, it shows "Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int"

Comment: The current error is unrelated to `custom_flatten` (you can remove the function without changing the error).

Comment: Note that this is missing the definition of `init`.

Comment: A suggestion: if you're not allowed to use standard library functions to solve a problem, _do it anyway_ and then faithfully reimplement those functions once you have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

So (and I'm an ocaml beginner, so do double-check my thinking) you have `mapi_Two` defined like this:

```
let rec mapi_Two f index list =
...
    let result = f index x in
...
```

So - it takes a function, index and list and passes the index as the first parameter to that function. I'm assuming the index is an `int`.

Then when you call it:

```
mapi_Two (fun (source, target) i -> Transfer (source, target))
```

You are passing `mapi_Two` a function that takes `(source, target)` (which are the `a * b` in your error message) rather than an int.

Answer (score 1):

Though `mapi_Two` is the source of the error you've posted, [as identified by Richard Huxton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77358573/15261315), it may be worth pointing out that as of OCaml 4.14 and later, reimplementing `List.flatten` is more straightforward than the accumulator approach you've used.

```
let rec flatten = function
  | [] -> []
  | []::xs -> flatten xs
  | (x::xs)::ys -> x :: flatten (xs :: ys)
```

The downside to this is that it isn't tail-recursive. Adding an accumulator solves this, but so does [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html).

```
let[@tail_mod_cons] rec flatten = function
  | [] -> []
  | []::xs -> flatten xs
  | (x::xs)::ys -> x :: flatten (xs :: ys)
```

The strategy of reimplementing library functions is A) a good way to learn, and B) a good way to circumvent homework limitations that forbid use of those functions. But, you need to ensure you reimplement their interfaces faithfully and use them accordingly.